# Edit Cutecom Launcher icon 16.04

Tags: launcher, icons

Cutecom installed on 16.04: Its launcher icon is identical to the Terminal icon.  What is the procedure to change the icon?

[Target icon](https://dl2.macupdate.com/images/icons256/51344.png)
[image]

Comment: Do you have an icon you wish to use for cutecomm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to edit cutecom's .desktop file, location is `/usr/share/applications/kde/cutecom.desktop`

Edit the Icon= line to location/name of icon you want to use. For single user use you can just put the icon in your Pictures folder, for multi-user use place it /usr/share/pixmaps or /usr/share/app-install/icons (or any icon folder in /usr

Then just edit the .desktop using full path, ex. here I placed terminal.svg in my Pictures folder, using nano as root, edit is line 7, using the full path to terminal.svg

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/kde/cutecom.desktop`

[image]

If you're not happy with your icon try to find a 48x48 svg, I can upload a red one if you'd like..

Comment: Excellent explanation: please upload an icon and its link.  Successfully implemented the procedure :)

Comment: Not home now for red one, here's a green one, dl link good for about 30 days or so as site turns over files  `wget https://0x0.st/ePg.svg`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik9EQ.png -O /usr/share/icons/cutecom.png
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kde/cutecom.desktop
# Icon = /usr/share/icons/cutecom.png
```